# Translate into Latin: "To will the impossible" and "with will and sacrifice"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, motto

Hello and thank you in advance. Two phrases I am interested being in Latin:

"To will the impossible" 
and 
"With will and sacrifice"

First one being similar to "If there is a will, there's a way."
And the second embraces the virtues of willpower and selflessness.

Again, thank you

Comment: Welcome to the site! As you have two distinct questions, I recommend asking them separately. Can you edit one of them out from this one and ask it as a new question?